# Application getting Unfortunately stopped when my edittext field make null

Tags: java, android, xml

I am confused what might be the reason behind this error.While making my edittext field null after entering a digit into it my application is getting crashed.can you find a solution for this situation ??

here is my code

java file

```
    public class CSLActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Common mApp;
    private AutoCompleteTextView clgName, conCent, loc;
    private MultiAutoCompleteTextView skill;
    private String[] qulify = new String[]{"Select Highest Qualification", "PG", "UG", "DIPLOMA"};
    public String abc, abcd;
    public ScrollView scrollView;
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    private String q;
    private Spinner level;
    private int ab = 1990;
    public EditText fullName, frm_yr, to_yr;
    private boolean ins = false;
    private boolean cIns = false;
    private Button next;
    private TextfieldValidator textfieldValidator;
    private AlphabetValidator alphabetValidator;
    private int i = 0, j = 0;
    private boolean exit = false;
    private String get;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_csl);

        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        fullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullName);
        level = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.level);
        clgName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.clg_name);
        conCent = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.concent);
        frm_yr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.frm_yr);
        to_yr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to_yr);
        skill = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.skill);
        loc = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        textfieldValidator = new TextfieldValidator();
        alphabetValidator = new AlphabetValidator();
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        frm_yr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //abc = frm_yr.getText().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //i = Integer.parseInt(frm_yr.getText().toString());
                //i = Integer.parseInt(abc.toString());
                i = Integer.parseInt(frm_yr.getText().toString());

            }
        });


        to_yr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //j = Integer.parseInt(to_yr.getText().toString());
                //j = Integer.parseInt(abcd.toString());
                j = Integer.parseInt(to_yr.getText().toString());
            }
        });


        new GetCollege(CSLActivity.this, progressBar, scrollView, clgName).execute();
        new GetCourse(CSLActivity.this, conCent).execute();
        new GetSkillSet(CSLActivity.this, scrollView, progressBar, skill).execute();
        new GetLocation(CSLActivity.this, scrollView, loc, progressBar).execute();


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, qulify);
        level.setAdapter(adapter1);
        level.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                get = level.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (get.equalsIgnoreCase("PG")) {
                    q = "1";
                } else if (get.equalsIgnoreCase("UG")) {
                    q = "2";
                } else {
                    q = "3";
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


        clgName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ins_name);
                clgName.setText(txt.getText().toString());
                conCent.requestFocus();
                ins = true;

            }
        });

        conCent.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display);
                conCent.setText(txt.getText().toString());
                cIns = true;
                frm_yr.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        loc.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ins_name);
                loc.setText(txt1.getText().toString());
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.next:

                        if (fullName.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            fullName.setError("Field Mandatory");
                            fullName.requestFocus();
                        } else if (!alphabetValidator.validate(fullName.getText().toString())) {
                            fullName.setError("Enter a Valid Name");
                            fullName.requestFocus();
                        } else if (get.equalsIgnoreCase("Select Highest Qualification")) {
                            level.requestFocus();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "select Qualification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (clgName.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            clgName.setError("Field Mandatory");
                            clgName.requestFocus();
                        } else if (conCent.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            conCent.setError("Field Mandatory");
                            conCent.requestFocus();
                        } else if (frm_yr.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            frm_yr.setError("Field Mandatory");
                            frm_yr.requestFocus();
                        } else if (to_yr.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            to_yr.setError("Field Mandatory");
                            to_yr.requestFocus();
                        } else if (i > j) {
                            to_yr.setError("Passed out year less than join year");
                            to_yr.requestFocus();
                        } else if (i == j) {
                            to_yr.setError("Check the year entered");
                            to_yr.requestFocus();
                        } else if (i <= ab) {
                            frm_yr.setError("Enter a valid Year");
                            frm_yr.requestFocus();
                        } else if (j <= ab) {
                            to_yr.setError("Enter a valid Year");
                            to_yr.requestFocus();
                        } else if (skill.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            skill.setError("Field Mandatory");
                            skill.requestFocus();
                        } else if (!textfieldValidator.validate(skill.getText().toString())) {
                            skill.setError("Enter a Valid Skill");
                            skill.requestFocus();
                        } else if (loc.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                            loc.setError("Field Mandatory");
                            loc.requestFocus();
                        } else if (!textfieldValidator.validate(loc.getText().toString())) {
                            loc.setError("Enter a Valid Location");
                        } else {
                            next.setEnabled(false);
                            new CslIns(CSLActivity.this, mApp.getPreference().getString(Common.u_id, ""), fullName.getText().toString(), q,
                                    clgName.getText().toString(), conCent.getText().toString(), frm_yr.getText().toString(), to_yr.getText().toString(),
                                    skill.getText().toString(), loc.getText().toString(), ins, cIns).execute();
                                    /*startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MailVerify.class));
                            finish();*/
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (exit) {
            mApp.getPreference().edit().putBoolean(Common.PAGE1, false).commit();
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Cancel Signup Process.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exit = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shuan.Project.signup.employee.CSLActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/fullName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
                    android:hint="Full Name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/level"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/clg_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/clg_name"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/concent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/concent"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/yr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Joined"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/frm_yr"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
                        android:hint="Year"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:maxLength="4"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Passed :"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/to_yr"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
                        android:hint="Year"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:maxLength="4"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_skill"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin">

                <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/skill"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Enter Your Skills"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="text" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/location"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/location"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/signin_border"
                android:text="START"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

log cat

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.shuan.Project, PID: 1432
                                                             java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                 at com.shuan.Project.signup.employee.CSLActivity$1.afterTextChanged(CSLActivity.java:95)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7998)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:9814)
                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:990)
                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:529)
                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:224)
                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:38)
                                                                 at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(BaseInputConnection.java:252)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:389)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5649)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: Please post logcat!

Comment: can you please mention where it exactly crashes?

Comment: it crashes while making null the fields  joined year and passed out year after entering a single characters in each field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
           if(to_yr.getText().toString().length != 0){ 
           j =Integer.parseInt(to_yr.getText().toString()); 
      }
   }
```

it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

At a first look, to me it seems to block on onAfterTextChanged, because is trying to parse an int from a String which is empty, so it just throws the error. 
Try to verify if the EditText is "" before of parsing the integer, if it is not "" or null do as your code, if it's "" or null give it a default value, like 0 or what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This crash is because of your code in afterTextChanged callback.
You should check if to_yr.getText is having some valid value before parsing it to the integer. Do not parse empty string.

Use below code:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(to_yr.getText()){
        j = Integer.parseInt(to_yr.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you parse the empty string and the **Integer** class throws exception named:

*Invalid int*

> java.lang.NumberFormatException

Do the check before parsing integer. For example

```
String s;

if(s != null && (!s.isEmpty())){
     Integer i = s.ParseInt();
}
```